# Parse data from leboncoin get stuck in captcha with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, parsing

I am using selenium to parse data from the french site leboncoin.fr with python and selenium. I have tried many solutions that I have found here in StackOverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667408/trouble-when-webscraping-leboncoin). Nonetheless I keep getting stuck in the captcha, I solve it manually to continue but then it launches it again non-stop so I can never reach the page itself.

Is there any other way to parse this web or to avoid getting stuck like this?

I have also tried this code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'./chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.leboncoin.fr/')
```

Comment: The problem you have is you want to wait something during the time to solve the capcha and continue automatically after capcha solved?

Comment: @Frenchy no the problem that I have is that I solve manually the captcha it says okay and reloads a new captcha again, I cannot pass that screen

Answer (score 0):

With just selenium, you cant avoid the captcha because leboncoin uses [Datadome protection](https://datadome.co/bot-protection/) .

I suggest you to take another approach, ip rotating for example, but its not easy and 100% functional.  you could search all informations about selenium and datadome, but i have not found things resolving your problem.

[Some informations here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62199222/website-using-datadome-gets-captcha-blocked-while-scraping-using-selenium-and-py/62205253#62205253)